# Incremental Loading in ListView WP8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have read the articles about how to do incremental loading when we scroll to  bottom of the list view, but how to achieve lazy loading when we scroll to top of the list. I want to add more items to the top of the list when the user reaches the top. Is there any way we can achieve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a solution for this. Rotate both controls.

For eg->

`<ListView x:Name="GridViewMain" IncrementalLoadingThreshold="2" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <ListView.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="180"></RotateTransform>
            </ListView.RenderTransform>
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListView.Resources>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplateGridViewMain">
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="#FF7C1A9B" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                        <Grid.RenderTransform>
                            <RotateTransform Angle="180"/>
                        </Grid.RenderTransform>
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" FontFamily="Tempus Sans ITC" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.Resources>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <StaticResource ResourceKey="DataTemplateGridViewMain" />
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>`

Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built in solution.

Here's an example that checks the ListViews scroll position and loads additional items once it is at the top.

```
// Attach to the view changed event
_scrollViewer = listview.GetFirstDescendantOfType<ScrollViewer>();
if (_scrollViewer != null)
{
    _scrollViewer.ViewChanged += OnViewChanged;
}
```

And the handler.

```
private void OnViewChanged(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // If scrollviewer is scrolled up
    if (_scrollViewer.VerticalOffset < 150)
    {
        // Start loading new items...
    }
}
```

*Handle with care:*

When adding items at the top, scroll position will change.

The check is very simple, is will only work if the scrollviewer can actually scroll.

Comment: how to handle the change in scroll position?

Comment: What exactly so you mean? There's scrollviewer.ChangeView().

Comment: while scrolling from bottom to top, when items are added, the scroll suddenly jumps to bottom. Any way to prevent this?

Comment: The ItemsStackPanel in the ListView has an [ItemsUpdatingScrollMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemsstackpanel.itemsupdatingscrollmode.aspx) Property. Also, to prevent it from jumping around, you have to scroll the scollviewer 1px down from the top.

Comment: I tried it, but was unable to fix it. Posted a question regarding it. ITs a general problem i am facing even with top to bottom list view. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29984051/list-view-resets-its-scroll-position-on-item-source-change