# Scroll from bottom to top in a listview

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app

I'm trying to recreate the functionality of the Messages app in a WinRT universal app. In the WinPhone project i've created a listview, and i've set the itemssource. Everything works fine, it loads more items as i scroll and all. 
However, it starts at the top of the list, and the user has to scroll down. How do i reverse, so that i start at the bottom, and scroll up?

The list is also utilizing the select modes, so the user can select multiple items and edit/delete them. So i can't just rotate the list and its items 180 degrees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built in solution for Loading additional items at the top.

[Here's a good start for implementing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29591835/incremental-loading-in-listview-wp8/29594470#29594470) but you still have to figure out the details.

You an scroll to the top using the ListView's [ScrollIntoView Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh968031.aspx) passing the first item as a parameter.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Not that it is going to discourage me though :)